# Error when importing BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-2to3

Executing script with usage of `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stewart\Desktop\dorkscan.py", line 13, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
  File "C:\PentestBox\base\python\Lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 53  
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3.  
 This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it  
 (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
```

Comment: Even though you didn't ask a question, I think the answer is already in the stacktrace:

`You need to convert the code, either by ...`

Comment: i tried to python setup.py install but it gives me an error i tried the second thing it gives me nothing ! im really confused to what should i do

Comment: Well it says you are trying to use python 2. What does `python --version` say? Did you try to call the script with `python3` instead?

Comment: `You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3`. This is pretty much self-explanatory :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to run the Python2 version of bs4 in Python3. To fix this, you should install the proper version of bs4.

- If you want to write in python2 `pip install BeautifulSoup4`
- python3 `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`

In the future, you should pay attention to the error messages python gives. They are very informative. For instance, yours' says

```
'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'
```

The solution is given in the error message.

Comment: The proper name of the package (and thus the one that should be `pip install`ed) is [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4), not [bs4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4).

Comment: @jwodder Thanks for catching my mistake. I've edited the answer, though bs4 is a squatter package and would have installed BeautifulSoup4 as well.